# Launching scripts from bash and directing outputs

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have a question about syntax of bash regarding launching scripts from within bash script.

My questions are:

1. I've seen the following syntax:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   python do_something.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &
   ```

   Can you please explain what is directed to `/dev/null`, and what is the meaning of `2>&1` if before already mentioned `/dev/null`?
2. In addition if I have a line defined like:

   ```
   python do_something.py > 2>&1 &
   ```

   how is that different?
3. If I have the same python file in many paths, how can I differentiate between each process after launching `ps -ef |grep python`.
   When I'm doing so, I get a list of processes which are all called `do_something.py`, it would be nice if I could have the full execution path string of each pid; how can I do that?

**NOTE:** The python file launched is writing its own log files.

Comment: have a look at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial ..

Comment: For (2), running `:  > 2>&1 &` generates 
``-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `2'`` — it is deemed invalid because there is no filename for the `>` redirection.  That wasn't what I expected; I thought the file name would be the `2>&1` hieroglyph.  (The `:` is a standard shell (built-in) command that does nothing successfully, assuming its arguments and I/O redirections were successful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, **diclaimer**: I don't have access to a bash right now, so I might be wrong.

1. Let's break your command: `python do_something.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

   `python do_something.py` will run your command
   `> /dev/null` will redirect stdout to /dev/null
   `2>&1` will redirect stderr to stdout
   `&` will fork your process and run in background

   So your command will ignore stdout/stderr and be run in background which 
   is equivalent to the command `python do_something.py >& /dev/null &` [**[1]**](https://superuser.com/questions/335396/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-bash)[**[2]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)
2. `python do_something.py > 2>&1 &`:

   `> 2` will redirect stdout to a file named 2
   `>&1` will redirect stdout to stdout (yes stdout to stdout)
   `&` will fork your process and run in background

   So this command is *almost* equivalent to `python do_something.py >2 &`, 
   it will redirect the output to a file named 2 (eg: `echo 'yes' > 2>&1`)

   **Note**: the behavior of `>&1` is probably unspecified.
3. Since you have run your command using `&`, your command will be fork and
   run in background, therefore I'm not aware of any way to do it in that 
   case. You can still lookup the `/proc` directory **[3]** to see from 
   which directory your command have been run thought.

**[1]**: [What is the difference between &> and >& in bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/335396/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-bash)
**[2]**: [In the shell, what does “ 2>&1 ” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)
**[3]**: `ls -l /proc/$PROCCESSID/cwd`

Comment: @user6775110: can you explain role of each & in the expression: `python do_something.py >& /dev/null &`

Answer (score 1):

1) stdout (Standard Output) is redirected to /dev/null and stderr (error messages) is redirected to standard output i.e console.

- 1>filename : Redirect stdout to file "filename."
- 1>>filename: Redirect and append stdout to file "filename."
- 2>filename : Redirect stderr to file "filename."
- 2>>filename: Redirect and append stderr to file "filename."
- &>filename : Redirect both stdout and stderr to file "filename."

3) Using the **ps auxww** flags, you will see the full path to output in both your terminal window and from shell scripts. "ps manual":

-w         Wide output. Use this option twice for unlimited width.

Comment: You've not yet explained the `2>&1` notation.  You might include a URL reference such as `[I/O Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections)` which displays as [I/O Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections).

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

1, 2. `>` redirects whatever that is printed in `stdout` as result of executing the command (in your case `python do_something.py`) to a file called `/dev/null`. The `/dev/null` is kind of a black hole. Whatever you write to it disappers.

`2>&1` redirects the output of `stderr` (which has fd as 2) to `stdout` (whose fd is 1).

Refer [I/O redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) for more info about redirections.

Refer [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/zeros.html) link for more info about `/dev/null`